# git rebase remote, but keep changes locally for later commit

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-remote

I goofed and committed development changes on the master, and pushed them upstream. Whats the best way to back out those changes from the remote repo, but keep a branch locally for later merging into master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to get your branches in order then do a forced push:

```
git checkout master        # though you're probably already there
# create the branch you should've committed to instead of master
git branch local-changes
# put master back where it belongs
git reset --hard <commit-master-should-be-at>
# and push it to origin!
git push -f
```

All the usual caveats about how this'll screw with anyone who's pulled from the upstream repo apply!

Comment: Why change history instead of just using `git revert` to undo the changes?

Comment: @jamessan: Because the OP explicitly said *rebase* in the question title (and tags). The assumption here is that this is "oops, I just pushed that - quick, before anyone notices!"

Comment: I wish I was that smart, I just assumed rebase is what is needed. Would revert be a better option?

Comment: @Corey: If no one has pulled, do this. If any one has, it'll be kinder to them if you revert the mistaken commits. See `git-revert` - it creates commits with reversed diffs that cancel out previous commits.